# What does a large spectral norm mean?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, machine-learning, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Suppose I have a data set $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, where $n$ is the number of samples and $d$ is the number of measurements. I find that the largest eigenvalue of $X^TX$ is a very large number.

Someone else comes along and says they have done some normalization, and they get a much smaller largest eigenvalue for $X^TX$. In addition, our classifier is doing better on the new data set too.

What can we say about this situation? Is the new data set more separable? Is the spectral norm of $X$ an indicator of some property?

Comment: Could you please briefly comment on what classification is about? Or link to where such clarification is provided?

Comment: It seems like you need to clarify where normalisation takes place. If you are normalising $X$ by taking all columns to have unit length and then computing $X^TX$ then normalisation should not really have much effect on making the data more separable. It is advisable in general to normalise data you have, just so that you don't ever run into floating point overflow problems (this is just a good idea in scientific computing).

Comment: The normalization is done carefully using different techniques on different features. It can be regarded as a careful feature extraction. The main question is whether there is a measure to quantify this improvement on the data set somehow.